# How to Precompile <bits/stdc++.h> header file in ubuntu 20.04 / 22.04?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, precompiled-headers

Is there any way to precompile the `<bits/stdc++.h>` header file in ubuntu 20.04 like we can do in Windows OS so that I can execute programs faster in my Sublime text editor?

I use the FastOlympicCoding extension for fast execution, but I miss the old way of using an input-output file. I searched everywhere but didn't find any 'layman' approach to do that.

Comment: Odd. I'd expect the instructions to be exactly the same, excepting the minor syntax differences between the two OS shells..

Comment: Side note: I know you're in this for speed -of-writing, but you should give some thought to what this does to speed-of-troubleshooting. Here's a simple example of the sorts of weirdness that you can face: https://godbolt.org/z/cejjKevfr

Comment: @user4581301 OP is referring to Visual Studio's precompiled c/c++ headers I think, its not an OS feature

Comment: Yes, I'm including the header file directly, I understand it gives extra overhead to compile all those "not used" header files. Still, I wanted to know the way to pre-compile it in Ubuntu as I recently shifted from Windows to Linux!

Comment: @pm100 Makes sense. I figured GCC on both sides.

Comment: @nanofarad Precompiling `<bits/stdc++.h>` is its intended use.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, good to know

Comment: @user4581301 This has nothing to do with `<bits/stdc++.h>`, the problem is with `using namespace std;`. You get the same error if you `#include <iterator>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat True, but it's the cascade of silliness. You have to do a bunch of things "wrong" to get into that situation. Including the entire C++ Standard Library makes it much more likely that you'll stumble over an identifier that you didn't even know exists.

Comment: Rather off topic, but I would seriously consider forgetting that there's even such a header file in existence. You should never use the `bits/std++` header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, After having help from @TedLyngmo's answer and doing a little bit more research, I decided to answer the question myself with more clear steps.

**PS**: *This answer will be more relatable to those who are using sublime with their custom build file and are on Linux OS (Ubuntu).*

> 1. You need to find where **stdc++.h** header file is present, so open the terminal and use the command:
>
>    `find /usr/include -name 'stdc++.h'`
>
>    Output:
>
>    `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/stdc++.h`
> 2. Go to the above location and open the terminal there and now we are ready to precompile **bits/stdc++.h** header file.
> 3. Use the following command:
>
>    `sudo g++ -std=c++17 stdc++.h`
> 4. You'll observe **stdc++.h.gch** file is now created implying that precompiling is done.

**PS:** You need to use **sudo** as we need root privileges when **g++**  makes stdc++.h.gch file.

**NOTE:** Here as I was using the **c++17** version in my custom build file so I mentioned c++17, you can use whatever version you are using.

It worked perfectly for me so I hope it helps you too!

Comment: Oh heck no.  Besides the issues of including `bits/stdc++.h` in your program (directly or indirectly), this answer will cause serious problems if an update changes the actual header files in `/usr/include/...`.

Comment: Any better alternative then ?

Answer (score 4):

An example creating a precompiled header:

```sh
mkdir -p pch/bits &&
g++ -O3 -std=c++20 -pedantic-errors -o pch/bits/stdc++.h.gch \
   /usr/include/c++/11/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/stdc++.h
```

Check what you got:

```sh
$ file pch/bits/stdc++.h.gch
pch/bits/stdc++.h.gch: GCC precompiled header (version 014) for C++

$ ls -l pch/bits/stdc++.h.gch
-rw-r--r-- 1 ted users 118741428  8 mar 23.27 pch/bits/stdc++.h.gch
```

A program using it:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> foo{1, 2, 3};
    for(auto v : foo) std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

Example compilation (put `-Ipch` first of the `-I` directives):

```sh
$ strace -f g++ -Ipch -O3 -std=c++20 -pedantic-errors -o program program.cpp 2>&1 | grep 'stdc++.h'
[pid 13964] read(3, "#include <bits/stdc++.h>\n\nint ma"..., 122) = 122
[pid 13964] newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "pch/bits/stdc++.h.gch", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118741428, ...}, 0) = 0
[pid 13964] openat(AT_FDCWD, "pch/bits/stdc++.h.gch", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY) = 4
```

Comment: Only 118MB?  Cheap as chips.  Voted you up and added a refinement to your answer.  I don't know if it works because I can't test it (hint hint)

Comment: I didn't really understand the answer. Can you make it a little simple? also in usr/include/c++/11 these x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/stdc++.h directories aren't present, so after running your command it gives error: x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/stdc++.h: No such file or directory.

Comment: @princebansal_ You'll have to replace the path to `bits/stdc++.h` to the path where it's installed on your system. `find /usr/include -name 'stdc++.h'` should find it. Other than that, is there something specific that you'd like me to clarify in the answer?

Comment: @princebansal_ Glad to hear it, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You **should not** `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` from ths source code, for at least two reasons:

- It's not portable, so it would need to be guarded by ugly `#ifdef`s.
- Unlike GCC, Clang never uses PCHs for `#include`s.

Instead you should include the PCH using the `-include` flag. This is the only option accepted by both GCC and Clang.

1. Precompile the header using `g++ -xc++-header /path/to/bits/stdc++.h -o stdc++.h.gch`.
2. Include it with `-include`: `g++ foo.cpp -include stdc++.h`.

Notice that `-include` automatically appends `.gch` to the filename; the current directory doesn't have to contain `stdc++.h`.

If there's no `.gch` file, `-include` falls back to including the regular non-PCH header, if it exists. If both exist in the include path, the PCH gets precedence.

Comment: I understand the severeness of using bits/stdc++.h, Just wanted to Know how we can do that in Linux OS so that doing coding as practice would be more efficient as being coder per se. Thanks for your answer too, Will definitely try this.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Ted's answer, I would actually do something like this (untested):

my_pch.h:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>          // might need to specify the full path here
```

And then:

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++20 -pedantic-errors -o pch/bits/my_pch.h.gch my_pch.h
```

And finally, your program would look like this:

```
#include "my_pch.h"

int main() {
    // ...
}
```

This means you don't need to put `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` directly in your source files, since that is a bit naughty.  It also means you can add other include files to `my_pch.h` if you want them.

I think, also, it wouldn't cost you anything to put, say, `#include <string>` after including `my_pch.h`, and that doing that sort of thing might be wise.  If you're ever going to move the code into production you could then recompile it with `my_pch.h` empty.

---

**Edit:** Another thing to consider (which I also can't test) is just to include the things you actually use (`string`, `vector`, whatever) in `my_pch.h`.  That will probably pull in `bits/stdc++.h` anyway, when building the precompiled header.  Make it a comprehensive list so that you don't need to have to keep adding to it.  Then you have portable code and people won't keep beating you up about it.

Comment: Yes, your version works too. I started out with a similar version but decided to go for minimal (for some reason - it was late). I like this better than mine now that I've slept on it :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't even see that answer. I missed it since it came in later but I missed it now too (I'm not very observant it seems). :-) It'd be a sure +1 if it had not focused so much on the obvious misuse of internal headers. The question and the answers need only to deal with precompilation (in my mind). Leavin poking at the use of `bits/...` alone is hard, but in this case, precompiling headers is probably (maybe) even what the implementors had in mind. Just guessing.