Setting up sublime text error: -std=c++17: g++.exe: command not found
I am on Mac OS and I am new to programming in general.
I was setting up Sublime text for competitive programming using the guide at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/setting-up-sublime-text-for-cpp-competitive-programming-environment/
Following the last instructions, I sourced to the header files in bits folder from terminal and ran the command: g++ stdc++.h -std=c++17
Error shown: clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
After this, whenever I have tried to run code from Sublime text, error shown: -std=c++17: g++.exe: command not found
However, I can still run same code from the default XCode editor without any problem. So I thought the problem was internalised. Previously I had updated the Sublime text preferences setting using the following  code (is this the source of the problem?):
{
    "linters": {
        "g++": { // https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-gcc
            "disable": false,
            "executable": ["g++-11"],
            "args": ["-DLOCAL", "-std=c++17", "-O2", "-Wall", "-Wextra", "-Wshadow", "-Wconversion", "-Wfloat-equal", "-Wduplicated-cond", "-Wlogical-op"],
            "I": [],
            "excludes": [],
        },
    },
}

I checked that g++ compiler is already installed (installed using brew). I am not sure how to check for the $PATH

That site have a very bad reputation around here. It tend to give out bad advice, show bad and sometimes even invalid code, and is generally not good for beginners. One example is that you attempt to build a header file, which you should not do. And the header file is a really bad one that you shouldn't even use.

If you're serious about learning C++, then you need to invest in some good books. They might be expensive, but will teach you everything you need and more, and will be worth it in the long run. If you absolutely can't afford a book, I've heard good things about https://www.learncpp.com.

I don't know what your goal is, but if it is to learn to program then you ae not going to get very far doing competitive programming. Buy a book, sign up for a course, these are better alternatives to learn programming.

Checking the path, just open a terminal and type echo $PATH.

Also note that you are following instructions for Windows when you are using a Mac. Even if those instructions are good for Windows (which I don't think they are) then there is no certainty that they are good when translated to the Mac.

what are the contents of the CP.sublime-build file that the instructions told you to create? For how to actually precompile stdc++.h see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401614/how-to-precompile-bits-stdc-h-header-file-in-ubuntu-20-04-22-04, note that this will only work if you've installed GCC, by default GCC on macos is actually clang and uses libc++ not libstdc++ and doesn't have that header
